# How do Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message on windows 10?

Tags: apache, windows-10

I came across this error message today when trying to install and set up the latest version of apache, whenever I type `httpd` in `cmd` I get this:

> AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::bd5f:7651:b4a3:3a1a. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message

Comment: Thank you for asking this query, I made changes in windows hosts file as well but message remains the same.

Answer (score 18):

```
ServerName www.example.com:8080
```

On this line remove the hashtag and use your domain name if you have one other use

```
localhost:8080
```

Comment: Thank you this solved my problem, just to be more specific we're making changes in C:\Apache24\conf\httpd.conf line number 222